# Wifi automatically turns off when ethernet connects

Tags: wifi, ethernet

I have a need for Wifi and ethernet to be up and connected at the same time.  The Wifi is connected to the internet and the ethernet is connected to other computers on the local ethernet.  The local ethernet has the ip set manually.

The Wifi is on 192.168.1.X (subnet 255.255.255.0) and the ethernet is 192.168.5.X (subnet 255.255.255.0).  This should allow me to connect to both and have proper routing.

This works for about 30 seconds and then the Wifi disconnects.  I set the service order so that Wifi was the highest but that doesn't fix anything.  Everytime I turn the Wifi back on it will connect and then automatically disconnect 30-60 seconds later.

I searched and can't seem to find a setting to keep the Wifi from disconnecting when the ethernet connects

Comment: Mac model, macOS version?

Comment: Also, can you clarify if the adapter actually turns off or if it just disconnects.